# String previous last index

Tags: java, csv

Is there a simple way of getting the penultimate delimited substring of a string?

```
String original = "/1/6/P_55/T_140";
```

In this example, the resulting substring would be `"P_55/T_140"`

I would like to find the index of forward slash at the beginning of this substring (`/`)

I know `String.lastIndexOf()` calling twice would help. But looking for a cleaner approach which is generic. Perhaps to any N.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But looking for a cleaner approach which is generic. Perhaps to any N.

Calling `String.lastIndexOf(int,int)` in a loop is going to be quite efficient, and arguably pretty clean:

```
    int pos = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pos = str.lastIndexOf('/', pos - 1);
    }
    String out = str.substring(pos + 1);
```

This can be easily turned into a helper function taking `str`, `'/'` and `n`, and returning `out`.

Comment: This is also going to be a perfectly fast solution, too.

Answer (score 1):

To get the folder name where the media file resides

/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20170812-WA0000.mp4

use the below code

```
String folderName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/',filePath.lastIndexOf('/')-1),filePath.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

returns the folderName as 'whatsApp Video'

Answer (score 1):

To get previous last string

This -
https://developer.co/RTsMlGTsCj/share

To -
RTsMlGTsCj

Use this

Kotlin

```
val removeDomainName : String = scanResult.substring(
                scanResult.lastIndexOf('/', scanResult.lastIndexOf('/') - 1),
                scanResult.lastIndexOf('/')
            )
            val profileCode: String = removeDomainName.removePrefix("/")
```

Java

```
String removeDomainName = scanResult.substring(scanResult.lastIndexOf('/',scanResult.lastIndexOf('/')-1),scanResult.lastIndexOf('/'));
```